# Foundation for responsive rows

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid-layout

I have a possibly trivial question regarding responsive design.

The fluid grid for columns is amazing. However, is there any grid system for rows? For example, if I want to have a box that has `margin-top` in large screen but none in small screen, how would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use media-query, for example that you want is here:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gJkJT/1)

**CSS:**

```
div{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:#ddd;
    margin-top:0px;
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  div{
    margin-top:100px;
  }
}
```

with some `transition` it will look better. ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gJkJT/2/))

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something called a media-query. It lets you specify CSS but only if the browser viewport is less than (or greater than) a specified size. According to the [src](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/_variables.scss) the small screen is triggered at less than 768px. So a rule like the one you are asking for might look like this:

```
<style>
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .row {
      margin-top:0
    }
  }
</style>
```